# Does Samsung KIES backup hidden photos in galery?

Tags: backup, samsung-kies, hidden

I made a hard reset on a friend's SAMSUNG I9082 GRAN DUOS and he forgot to tell me about his hidden items.

On the KIES I selected all the possible options to keep, like a full backup (including configs, all pics and stuff).

I wanna know if KIES keeps these hidden items on backup. Because right after I've had restored the backup there were no more hidden items.

Is that possible that the item have missed his "hidden" property and it's still there or It really wasn't included on KIES backup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DON'T use the phone until you try this*

You can retrieve the files you deleted. Those files are still in the memory of your phone just not visible, the data is waiting to be written over by new data. *So from now on don't use the phone to take any more pics, to save anymore data, music, or installing any apps until recover has been done.* The extensions of the hidden files will be different than normal.  When recovering look for the ext that the files were hidden under.

Then the best way to retrieve your deleted files, is to use a recovery program.

1. Download and install the recovery program on your computer.
2. With the phone plugged into USB, goto "My Computer", note the drive letter assigned to your phone.
3. Start the program and select the drive letter that was assigned to the phone, click *"START"*.
4. Now the scanning process will automatically start to look for the deleted files.
5. The returning results are all recoverable items.
6. Select a location to save your files at.
7. Select the files you want recovered,  click *"RECOVER"*

Answer (score 0):

No, Kies doesn't backup hidden items over the gallery, the hidden pictures are now lost.